# creating tble error in sql developer ora-00904 invalid identifier

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

```
CREATE TABLE "dbo"."NPIData_HCP_PracticeAddress"(
       [NPI] [varchar](55) NULL,
       [ProviderPracticeAddress1] [varchar](255) NULL,
       [ProviderPracticeAddress2] [varchar](255) NULL,
       [ProviderPracticeCity] [varchar](55) NULL,
       [ProviderPracticeState] [varchar](55) NULL,
       [ProviderPracticePostalCode] [varchar](55) NULL,
       [ProviderPracticePhone] [varchar](55) NULL,
       [ProviderPracticeFax] [varchar](55) NULL
)
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Please state a clear problem.

Comment: hi  turing i am new to this sry dint specify the question very perfect.. the thing is i am trying to create a table in oracle sql developer and i am facing  the error as ORA-00904 invalid identifier:   thanks @Turing85

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try your `CREATE TABLE` statement like below by removing those square brackets `[]`. In `Oracle` you use double quotes `""` for escaping. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/44c7d

```
CREATE TABLE "NPIData_HCP_PracticeAddress"(
       NPI varchar(55) NULL,
       ProviderPracticeAddress1 varchar(255) NULL,
       ProviderPracticeAddress2 varchar(255) NULL,
       ProviderPracticeCity varchar(55) NULL,
       ProviderPracticeState varchar(55) NULL,
       ProviderPracticePostalCode varchar(55) NULL,
       ProviderPracticePhone varchar(55) NULL,
       ProviderPracticeFax varchar(55) NULL
)
```

Comment: Error starting at line : 1 in command -

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01918: user 'DBO' does not exist
01918. 00000 -  "user '%s' does not exist"
*Cause:    User does not exist in the system.
*Action:   Verify the user name is correct.       this is the error i got bro..but somehow its ok thanks@rahul.

Comment: @DilipReddy, Do you really have a schema defined as `dbo`. See edit again in answer.

Comment: )
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01918: user 'DBO' does not exist
01918. 00000 -  "user '%s' does not exist"
*Cause:    User does not exist in the system.
*Action:   Verify the user name is correct.
Table "NPIData_HCP_PracticeAddress" created.   thanks bro now its worked..@rahul